# mlab: Could not open matlab, is it in

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to use Mlab in my Python script to call Matlab functions, however I'm getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mlab/mlabraw.py", line 58, in open
    ret.open()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ret' referenced before assignment
Exception AssertionError: AssertionError() in <bound method MlabWrap.__del__ of <mlab.mlabwrap.MlabWrap object at 0x7f83e8989450>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mlab/mlabraw.py", line 58, in open
    ret.open()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ret' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testMlab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mlab.releases import R2018a as matlab
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mlab/releases.py", line 125, in __getattr__
    return self.instances[name]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mlab/releases.py", line 63, in __getitem__
    self[k] = self.get_mlab_instance(k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mlab/releases.py", line 87, in get_mlab_instance
    instance = MlabWrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mlab/mlabwrap.py", line 405, in __init__
    self._session = mlabraw.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mlab/mlabraw.py", line 61, in open
    raise MatlabReleaseNotFound('Could not open matlab, is it in %s?' % matlab_path)
mlab.matlabpipe.UnixMatlabReleaseNotFound: Could not open matlab, is it in /home/yuh5/Matlab2018a/bin/matlab?
Exception AssertionError: AssertionError() in <bound method MlabWrap.__del__ of <mlab.mlabwrap.MlabWrap object at 0x7f83e8989450>> ignored
```

It did complained that Matlab was not installed in the expected path. And I hard coded this line in matlabpipe.py to:

```
if is_linux():
        # base_path = '/usr/local/MATLAB/R%d%s/bin/matlab'
        base_path = '/home/yuh5/Matlab%d%s/bin/matlab'
```

Here is the link to Mlab project on github:

[Mlab](https://github.com/ewiger/mlab/tree/master/src/mlab)

I also noticed that this project had been stopped being updated a few years ago, so should it still work with the newest version of Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define the path variable or set the library using `pip`.

As it doesn't look possible and the library does not look active I would recommend you to use live libraries in the vibrant space of numeric python. Particularly [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can be useful for the majority of your projects. They also have a very nice integration with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) that is a graphic library that replicates mathlab's plotting behaviour and syntax.

If you come from a heavy Matlab background here there is a useful link for the transition. http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html